# Find a missing date in excel using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Consider this part of the information I have on my Excel Worksheet. These are invoices with the number of the contract and the invoice emission date. Invoices must be issued every month.

```
column 0        column 1        column 2
contract      Execution ID   date of invoice
500               xxxx         2016.01.19
500               xxxx         2016.02.19
500               xxxx         2016.04.20    
500               xxxx         2016.04.20
504               xxxx         2016.04.21
504               xxxx         2016.04.21
511               xxxx         2016.12.22
511               xxxx         2017.01.19
511               xxxx         2017.02.21
511               xxxx         2017.03.21
511               xxxx         2017.06.20
511               xxxx         2017.09.22
511               xxxx         2017.10.20
511               xxxx         2018.01.22
511               xxxx         2018.02.19
511               xxxx         2018.03.23
```

I have more information on other columns but, for now, I just want a function that returns me, for each contract --> for each year of that contract --> the missing months of each year until today. The day does not matter.

Here's an example (knowing that the current date is September, 2018):

```
>> The missing months for the contract 511 are:
(year:2017, months:04, 05, 07, 08, 11, 12) and
(year:2018, months:04, 05, 06, 07, 08)*
```

- may include the current month, 09, or not

I presented that format to be returned, but it can by any, as long as I have the contract, the different years and the missing months for each year of each contract

I am a beginner at Python 3.x, as well as a programmer. So I have been studying the syntax, but I still didn't catch the logic to solve this problem.

Here's what I've tried so far (I apologize for the code being in portuguese):

```
import csv
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()


with open('remit_contracts.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    header = next(reader)
    justrow = [row for row in reader]
    rows = [header] + justrow # rows é uma lista de listas

A=[]
for i in range(len(justrow)):
    A.append(justrow[i][0].split(","))


# COLUMNS

def Coluna(num):
    col=[]
    for row in A:
        col.append(row[num])

    return col


# DIVIDE LIST "A" BY CONTRACTS


def ColunaNumero(num): # Transform strings in numbers
    l=[]
    for i in Coluna(num):
        l.append(eval(i))    
    return list(l)


def SetContractos (): # Transform strings in number sets (first column)
    l=[]
    for i in Coluna(0):
        l.append(eval(i))    
    return sorted(list(set(l)))

############################

def SetColuna (col): # Transform strings in number set
    l=[]
    for i in col:
        l.append(eval(i))    
    return sorted(list(set(l)))  # returs a set of the years

##########################  
def AnoMesTuplo():
    l=[]
    for i in Coluna(2):
        b=i.split(".")
        l.append((b[0],b[1]))
    return l
##########################
def DatasEmNumero():
    l=[]
    for i in Coluna(2):
        b=i.split(".")
        l.append((b[0],b[1]))
    return l

##################################    

def DataString():      # Returns list of [(contracto,(ano, mês))] for each contract 

    L=[]
    for c in SetContractos():
        l=[]
        for i,j in enumerate(ColunaNumero(0)):
            if j == c:
                l.append(AnoMesTuplo()[i])
        L.append((c,l))
    return L

#####################   

def SetSubtractor(l,L): # Returns subtraction of 2 sets
    return set(L)-set(l)

#######################

def MesesDoAno(ano):

    if ano == now.year:
        mesesdoano=[]

        for i in range(1,now.month):
            if len(str(now.month)) == 1:
                mesesdoano.append('0' + str(i))
            else:
                mesesdoano.append(str(i))

    else:
        mesesdoano= 
['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']

    return mesesdoano


#######################


def FaltamMeses(): #receives list of months and checks if there is any missing month

    for contracto,data in DataString(): #data is a list of tuples (ano,mes)

        anos=[]
        print("\n Para o contracto ",contracto,':')
        for ano,mes in data:
            anos.append(ano)
        set_anos=SetColuna(anos)

        lista=[]
        for i in set_anos:
            meses=[]
            lista.append((i,meses))
            for ano,mes in data:
                if ano == str(i):
                    meses.append(mes)
                    print (mes,' vai ser adicionado à lista meses.')
            print('Para o ano ', i,'faltam os meses ',SetSubtractor(meses,MesesDoAno(ano)))


    return None 

FaltamMeses()

# Problem 1: I need the missing months since the initial invoice emission date contracto
# Problem 2: I need missing months until the current date.
```

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your code please so that we can analyze it.

Comment: Ok, so here's what I've tried. It is natural that is poorly organized or inefficient.